# Transaction queue system not working properly

Tags: web3.js, transactions, send-transaction, node.js

so I am using helius for my transactions processing and am using the $49 plan. My app has quite a good traffic, exceeds rate limit if I don’t use a queue system. Does anyone have a good example of a queue system I can use to process transactions better? The one I have has some weird issues like it processes some transactions but some of the transactions gets stuck and stays in **Running** state forever.

The issue didn't happen before. Previously what I used to do was check if the any transaction was being processed at an interval, if yes then stop processing any new transaction. After the processing was done other items in the queue would get processed again. But that would create issues in case of time sensitive transactions such as swap.
Now what I do is, process the queue items every 2 seconds. Which is causing some transactions to halt at **running** state and never gets **completed**.

Previous code - Previous code

```
client.transactionsQueue.set("status", true);

setInterval(async () => {
    if (client.transactionsQueue.get("status")) {
        const transactionQueueToProcess = client.transactionsQueue.clone();

        if (transactionQueueToProcess.size) {
            client.transactionsQueue.set("status", false);

            for (const [ collectionName, transactionData ] of transactionQueueToProcess) {
                // transaction sending code
                client.transactionsQueue.delete(collectionName); // on tx success/fail delete the transaction data from queue

                await client.wait(100);
            }

            client.transactionsQueue.set("status", true);
        }
    }

    return;
}, 5 * 1000);
```

The above code used to work properly, but it was not good system for time sensitive transactions such as swap transaction. So I converted to the below code - This is the current queue system -

```
setInterval(async () => {
    const transactionQueueToProcess = client.transactionsQueue.clone(); // this is a Collection/Map

    if (transactionQueueToProcess.size) {
        transactionQueueToProcess.forEach((_, collectionName) => client.transactionsQueue.delete(collectionName));

        for (const [ collectionName, transactionData ] of transactionQueueToProcess) { // transactiondData is the transaction with signer info
            // transaction sending logic
            await client.wait(100);
        }
    }

    return;
}, 2 * 1000);
```

Which causes this issue (doesn't come out of **Running** state) -
[image: issue screenshot]